# MySQL / MariaDB not accepting JSON Format? Can not create Database

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I am currently using XAMPP/Apache with MariaDB on phpmyadmin.
I am trying to create a table based on my code using Doctrine and therefore Annotations for validating a form. I simply want to store the entered values from the form in the database.
In another example this worked perfectly fine.

But now i am having a "Checkbox field" that i guess is causing some kind of trouble when creating the database.

I am using those commands in the console:

```
php bin/console make:migration
```

Afterwards:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

When calling the 2nd one = when i try to create the table in my database i get the following errors:

```
Migration 20181121103017 failed during Execution. 
Error An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE pizza (id INT 
AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
phone VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
size INT NOT NULL, ingredient JSON NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:json_array)', delivery INT NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB':


SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in 
your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
'JSON NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:json_
array)', delivery INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY' at line 1
```

I am really not knowing what i am doing wrong at this point.

These are my annotations i have in my "Pizza.php" File.

```
// ------------------

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank(
 *     message = "E-Mail Address required"
 * )
 * @Assert\Email(
 *     message = "The email '{{ value }}' is not a valid email."
 * )
 * @Assert\Length(min="2", max="255")
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */

protected $email;

// ------------------

/**
 * @Assert\Range(min=0, max=3)
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */

protected $size;

// ------------------

/**
 *@Assert\NotBlank(
 *     message = "Choose at least 1 ingredient!"
 * )
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 */

protected $ingredient;

// ------------------

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank(
 *     message = "Choose a delivery option!"
 * )
 * @Assert\Range(min=0, max=1)
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */

protected $delivery;
```

The form itself is working perfectly fine, the validations do work the way i intended.

What exactly am i doing wrong?

If you need any more code from my "Pizza.php" (Entity Class) or my Controller File where i did my routing please let me know.

I am grateful for any help!

Comment: This looks like a mismatch between the version of mysql / mariadb you are running and what doctrine thinks you are running. That being said, personally I would normalize the database.

Comment: Is your MariaDB version lower than 10.2.7?
See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-data-type/

Comment: Yes, i am currently running: Server-Version: 10.1.19-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Comment: Can i simply update it our would it cause problems? Is there a workaround for this problem right now?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, it seems that Doctrine thinks it can use features that are not available on your version of mariadb.

If you tell doctrine which version you are using, it will select the correct datatype for that column, in this case probably `LONGTEXT` or something similar.

Depending on what you are using, it would look something like (using a yaml file in symfony for example):

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        server_version: '10.1'
```

Note that you would need to re-generate your migrations.

Like I mentioned in my comment, personally I would normalize the database and use a different table to link the pizza's to the ingredients to make searching and filtering easier.

Comment: I added it to my yml file but it didn't change my errors. Also the type "LONGTYPE" isn't recognized in either typing way unfortunately. I am using the format for the database which i have been told in my university course

Comment: @Calimera Have you removed the migrations that were already generated and had them re-generated with the modified settings?

Comment: Could you tell me how i can remove migrations? I just called make:migration over again! But i guess it wasn't removed this way

Comment: @Calimera No, I don't know what you are using exactly, but there probably is a `migrations` directory somewhere where all individual migrations are stored. You need to remove the ones that have not been executed yet in order to build them again.

Comment: I made a completely new database so that there could not be anything stored. I am still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

First check your mariadb version. Version 10.1 doesn't support JSON datatype and support for version 10.2 is incomplete.

A workaround is to the version in **doctrine.yaml** file to

`server_version: '5.6'`

then regenerate the getters and setters with

`php bin/console make:entity --regenerate`

then generate the migration file with

`php bin/console make:migration`

this will generate a migration file with datatype set to **LONGTEXT**.

Afterwards, in the ***src/Migrations*** open each file in there and check for any migration file with **JSON** as datatype and delete all migration with such datatype. Remember, if you don't delete these files, the next command iterates with each file persisting them to database one by one starting with the old one. If such file exist it will trigger the error again.

Lastly, run

`php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

which will persist all the migrations to database accordingly.

Comment: Was having this issue also, this worked great for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and i found this workaround:

In `Doctrine.yaml` found out that the server_version was higher than my MariaDB version, so I corrected that in this line:

```
   doctrine:
        dbal:
            server_version: '5.5'
```

I did not work until I manually erased the migrations i already did. You can found them in `src/Migrations`.

Then run again:

```
 php bin/console make:migration
 php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

And that did the work, hope it helps.