# Symfony | How to fix migration MySQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, database-migration

I am creating a login/registration system because I have never made one before. Using the Symfony framework, I am following their documentation (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html). It recommends that I create a User entity via

> php bin/console make:user

This creates my user entity and repository.

However, when I create the migration and migrate via running:

> php bin/console d:m:m

It returns me this syntax error:

```
Migration 20190502143453 failed during Execution. Error An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE user (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, roles JSON NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649F85E0677 (username), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB':

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
 near 'JSON NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649F85E067' at line 1
```

The full MySQL table creation that is returning the syntax error is found within the error message, however, this is the query by itself:

```
$this->addSql('CREATE TABLE user (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, roles JSON NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649F85E0677 (username), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB');
```

Having followed the steps up to the migration, I am unsure why I am getting a syntax error because it looks correct to me. The SQL was auto-generated.

If anyone knows how to solve this syntax error, any information would be appreciated.

If any more information is needed, I am happy to provide the information.

Best regards,

Steve.

Comment: Clearing the cache has not worked either.

Comment: Look this topic, I think solve your problem : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53410609/mysql-mariadb-not-accepting-json-format-can-not-create-database)

Comment: Yes, MariaDB and MySQL have diverged. You will have to change the `doctrine.dbal.server_version` and then recreate the migrations to ensure they are supported by your db-platform. I will mark this as duplicate for now.

Comment: @dbrumann this seems to have fixed my problem, cheers for linking me missed this thread